# Aggregate Forge Viewer - AGGREGATE_SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT

Tags: autodesk-forge

We are trying to find out the object id while double click on the equipment in the Forge Viewer. It is working if we do single click. But if we double click on the equipment in forge Viewer we are not able to get the selected equipment object id. we are getting parent object id of selected equipment.

how can we control this in our web application?

Is there a possibility to call AGGREGATE_SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT event in the button click event?

Note: We are using Forge Aggregate View and uploaded multiple models.

**Edit:**
We have tried the below doubleclick function but it was getting the parent object id. Example pls find the below extracted meta data:
[image]

In Aggregate Forge Viewer, we have selected object "AHU-B04IT-09A" and object id is 23611. But if we double click the AHU-B04IT-09A object in forge viewer we are getting their parent object id like 23613 instead of 23611. How to control this?
[image]

Comment: Could you please explain what you're trying to do? The event is called automatically (no matter whether there's multiple models in the viewer or just one) whenever the user selects or unselects something.

Comment: And you can subscribe to the event like so: `viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.AGGREGATE_SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT, function () { console.log('selection changed!'); })`

Comment: We are trying to find out the object id while double click on the equipment in the Forge Viewer. It is working if we do single click. But if we double click on the equipment in forge Viewer we are not able to get the selected equipment object id. we are getting parent object id of selected equipment. how can we control this in our web application. Note: We are using Forge Aggregate View and uploaded multiple models.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the additional information you've provided, it sounds like you want to be able to find out what is currently selected in the viewer after the user double-clicks something in the scene. That can be done using the following code snippet:

```js
viewer.canvas.addEventListener('dblclick', function (ev) {
  const selection = viewer.getAggregateSelection();
  console.log(selection);
});
```

[image]

Comment: We have used the above code but it is getting their parent object id only during the double click. For more details kindly check our edited question.

Comment: In that case it might be an issue with the viewer configuration, or with the specific model you're loading into it. Note that the viewer has a [selection mode](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#setselectionmode-mode) which controls what exactly gets selected when the user clicks on the canvas.